# How could this program be meaningful?

Tags: c

This program is stated to be neither a valid C program nor an invalid C one. But, to my understanding, it can't even be a program which is defined to be a sequence of instructions for the processing unit to compute.

The code is:
 
That's it. The author [alleges](http://www.ioccc.org/1994/smr.hint):

> Some C compilers will compile
>       an empty file into a program that does nothing.  But even if your
>       compiler can't, the build instructions supplied with this entry
>       will produce an executable file.  On most systems, the stdout
>       from the executable will exactly match original source.

I don't buy it. The *compilation* will succeed, yielding no instructions. However, the *linking* will fail as there is no `main` symbol to call. If it could be run, then the trick would work because it would output nothing and the source code actually contains nothing.

So, how could (literally, and in which environment) this `program` be considered a valid self reproducing program?

Note: it has been accepted as such by IOCCC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note this important line:

> But even if your compiler can't, the build instructions supplied with this entry will produce an executable file.

See the makefile for the actual build instructions:

```
smr: smr.c
    @${RM} -rf smr
    ${CP} smr.c smr
    ${CHMOD} +x smr
```

Put simply, this actually just creates an empty file with the executable bit set, which will, of course, do nothing.

Comment: "Some C compilers will compile an empty file into a program that does nothing." so this statement is potentially wrong, isn't it?

Comment: @black potentially, but all it takes is one example of a compiler that accepts an empty file to make the statement true (two examples if you want to satisfy Grice's maxim of quantity). We can assume that the author had such an example.

Comment: @black It is true that some old C compilers would do that, but I don't think any modern ones do. Either way, it's irrelevant.

Comment: @hobbs If the judges stated it you can be sure that it's true! Landon has a long history with Unix and C. So in answer to your question .. yes it happened.

Answer (score 5):

The "build instructions supplied with this entry" entail using [this Makefile](http://www.ioccc.org/1994/Makefile) to `make smr`.

If you look in the makefile, it doesn't invoke a C compiler at all; it just copies the empty source file to make an empty binary, and then `chmod +x`s it.

I don't know how true the assertion is that an empty executable file constitutes a program that does nothing "on most systems", but it does successfully do nothing on mine.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't look into the makefile where the trick resides. It's strange that you don't get "exec format error" though.